# Sort an array of objects according to position of a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of objects according to position of a 'restaurant' string in title field

```js
var test = [{
    title: 'Roy Restaurant'
  },
  {
    title: 'Restaurant'
  },
  {
    title: 'Roy Mega Restaurant'
  }
];

console.log(test.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.title.toLowerCase().indexOf('restaurant') > b.title.toLowerCase().indexOf('restaurant');
}));
```

so what my expected output is

```
var test = [
    {
    title : 'Restaurant'
  },
  {
    title : 'Roy Restaurant'
  },
  {
    title : 'Roy Mega Restaurant'
  }
];
```

so rank them by their `indexOf` value. Above, the first item `indexOf` value is 0 so it must be the first item, 2nd  `Roy Restaurant` because the word occurence is less than from the 3rd item.

Any help, ideas please?

Comment: what is the problem? Run the code and confirm if it is working as expected

Comment: You forget to ask a question. What do you need help with?

Comment: @Teemu I misinterpreted question. I thought we have to sort alphabetically. Hence marked it dupe but was about to retract vote as we have to sort based on index position. Though, I'm still confused as to what OP is looking for. Code provided works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort comparisons wants an integer not a bool.
From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to an index lower than
>   b (i.e. a comes first).

Change `>` to `-` on line 14.

```js
var test = [
    {
    title : 'Roy Restaurant'
  },
  {
    title : 'Restaurant'
  },
  {
    title : 'Roy Mega Restaurant'
  }
];

console.log( test.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.title.toLowerCase().indexOf('restaurant') - b.title.toLowerCase().indexOf('restaurant');
}) );
```